# Java, serializing non-static inner classes. Is there a trick?

Tags: java

I would like to serialize a non-static inner class in my java program. Though this is not allowed because my inner class (by default) has a reference to its outer class (which in this case is not serializable) so if I try to serialize it I get a NullPointerException for the outer class.

So is there a way to override the reference to the outer class and set it to transient so that it is not serialized by initialized every time and object of the inner class is created?

Comment: And why isn't your inner class static to begin with? Any reason for that?

Comment: How do you know which object would you initialise it to when deserializing?

Comment: I figure when I read in the object from the file it will set the reference to the object creating in, namely the outer class

Comment: nice answers to this question. One is "you can't" other with how to do it :)

Comment: @matheszabi well, I also give the solution: make it static...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't: if your inner class is not `static`, its initialization state *depends* on the instance of the outer class by definition. This, because you could not get an instance of your inner class without having an instance of the outer class to begin with.

And since the outer class is not `Serializable`, you cannot serialize the instance of the outer class, therefore you cannot serialize the instance of the inner class.

Or just make the inner class static and be done with it...

Comment: Another quick question. Can I serialize an object that contains objects of non-serializable classes? I am sure not.../

Comment: Effectively, you cannot. In the situation you described, you can consider that the reference to the outer, non serializable class is a "hidden instance variable" of your inner class instance. For a class to be serializable, all of its variables must be serializable, unless they are declared `transient`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make the implicit reference to the enclosing instance `transient`, but what you *could* do is redesign to make it a nested (static) class and pass the enclosing instance explicitly in a constructor argument. Then you'd need an explicit variable in your nested class, which you'd be allowed to tag as `transient`.

Comment: You still need a means of knowing what to assigning it to when deserialized.

Answer (score 0):

The automated serialization has a few negative parts: if you change the field name or you change the visibility of a field, than the deserialization will not work, more over: it will take a lot more space objects saved "automatically". For this reason almost always I am serializing / deserializing classes manually: write an int, write a string than read it back. 
With this method you can write the none static innner class deserialization as you want it